# run php artisan serve on vps permanently

Tags: php, laravel

When running of laravel site, it requires `php artisan serve` command. Now, I want to execute this on a VPS web server **permanently**. It means that, I want to run this on the webserver and not on my local pc. The problem is, I don't know how it is done.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel doesn't require the `artisan:serve` command, it requires a web server, and what the command does is that it just starts the php built-in server.

In other words, in your hosting, you just have to correctly set up nginx to point to your public folder and it should work normally.

Answer (score 3):

In Vps server you dont need to run php artisan serve.Just point your domain to your laravel project folder
for example if your project folder laravel then point your domain to

```
laravel/public
```

> The `Serve command is just a shortcut for the PHP Builtin Webserver,
>   something PHP has out of the box, so the point of using it is to start
>   testing your application as fast as you could, you just need to
>   install PHP, Composer and your application is up (if you don't need
>   anything else, of course). But if you already have Nginx installed,
>   there is no point at all, just use it.

It's not wise to use the Builtin Webserver in production.

Yuo can read more about here
http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Ref:
[Whats the point of running Laravel with the command 'php artisan serve'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892462/whats-the-point-of-running-laravel-with-the-command-php-artisan-serve)

Comment: thanks. By the way, on some other hostings, I have read that in some case, they need to reset the server. In local pc, we just simple press CTRL + C and then run `php artisan again`. How should we do this on vps?

Comment: if you are using windows pc then you can use putty .if its ubuntu you can connect thorugh terminal